# In a java gradle project, can I reference a test class from a main class?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a gradle project with *src/main/java/coolpackage/currentClass.java* and *src/test/java/coolpackage/desiredClass.java*.  Is it possible to import desiredClass into currentClass?

"import coolpackage." will cause it to think I am referring to the dev package instead of the test package, and it doesn't recognize packages above it like "test".

Comment: If the classes are in the same package, there is no need to Import it.

Comment: That has nothing to do with packages: gradle purposefully doesn't compile test classes with production classes, because you don't want to use test classes in production code. The production code should completely be isolated from test classes and libraries, and gradle makes sure it is. So, test classes have access to production classes and libraries, obviously, but the inverse is false.

Answer (score 1):

With the standard gradle project setup this is impossible, as gradle doesn't compile anything under src/test for use with production code. This can be achieved by editing your sourceSets in your build.gradle like so:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            srcDir 'src/test/java'
        }
    }
}
```

Having said that, I would question why you would ever need to do this. Test classes shouldn't be used in production code, and this therefore seems like an indication that something is wrong to me.